# There exists any ASP.NET News letter Integration API

Tags: api, newsletter

Implementing constant contact in asp.net

Comment: Please give more detail on what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense. You'll have to add more detail. Do you mean you want to create an RSS feed? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

Comment: Any minute now, people will begin marking your question to be closed, since you apparently can't be bothered to add detail.

Comment: Not sure what the question is all about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i am implementing in my project

The [Constant Contact APIs](http://developer.constantcontact.com/doc/reference) allow you to manage contacts in your account in various ways.  By utilizing contacts collection and resource, you can add, edit, unsubscribe contacts as well as modify their contact list memberships.

If you are interested in more detailed information about the actual collection and resource for contacts, please refer to the Contacts Collection and Resource Reference.

The following tasks are supported currently:

Listing All Contacts
Creating a Contact
Obtaining a Contact's Information
Updating Contact Information
Searching for a Contact by Email Address
Searching for Contacts by Last Updated Date

http://developer.constantcontact.com/doc/reference
http://developer.constantcontact.com/doc
[c# sample code](http://developer.constantcontact.com/node/35)

[Using the Constant Contact API with ASP.NET](http://www.codescene.com/2008/09/using-the-constant-contact-api.php)

Sample Upload Forms in .NET
Getting Started with the Upload Forms in .NET

[ASP Upload Form sample application.](http://developer.constantcontact.com/samples/upload_forms/netdoc)

Authentication data
Create a New Contact
Add or Edit a Contact
List all Contacts
Unsubscribe a Contact
Remove a Contact
Application class diagram
Installation guide
Customize displayed lists
How-To use it

Comment: If you think this is an excellent question, then could you please tell us what the question was?